# Problem with documents in Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash, search

I need help in this problem: I have changed my username (in all the config files like shadow, user, group, etc.) from `osca` to `oscar`.

Of course, I've changed the `/home/osca` directory to `/home/oscar` as well. All the system works like a charm with quantal quetzal, but when I try to search in any of my personal directories from the dash, the Download directory for example, Ubuntu shows me this error:

```
Can't find «/home/osca/Downloads»
```

It's like Unity doesn't recognize the new name of the home. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the standard procedure to do such a task is to use the command usermod and not to mess with the os files... 
Have a look at [usermod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/usermod.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /home/oscar /home/osca
```